# how to Delete app bundle from play store in 2024?

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an app bundle with ads in it and later I removed ads and uploaded multiple updated versions. But it still giving me this error or warning about data safety form. I do not see any option to disable or inactivate or delete that old app version. No test channels using that app version either or is at least the track is paused and track with new version enabled.
It showed that the warning has been resolved or addressed previously but still time to time an email is sent about data safety issue and the warning came back.

I do not see any option to declare app version specific data safety form.

As I do not see any option to delete that version so old SO questions on this topic is not relevant or at least I could not utilize.

Does anyone know anything about deleting that app version or something that will make that old app bundle removed to remove this warning?

image of the warning:
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I got the solution here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/community-guide/246555298/